# Django sql name of queryset field for RawSql

Tags: python, django

I need to generate a pretty large GeoJSON dataset. Serializing the queryset to geojson works but is terribly slow. In my case ~30 seconds. Using the PostGIS `ST_AsGeoJSON({geometry_field})::json` and then creating the datastructure from that queryset takes a couple of seconds, producing the exact same result.

So, to use this method around my code, I have a function `geojson_queryset(queryset, geom_field, pk_field, other_fields)` (quoted in full below). I originally wrote:

```
 features_queryset = queryset.extra(
     select={'geojson_queryset_result': f'ST_AsGeoJSON({geometry_field})::json'})\
     .values(*all_fields)
```

But reading the QuerySet API doc for extra(), the method is deprecated and should rather be written as:

```
features_queryset = queryset.annotate(
    geojson_queryset_result=RawSQL(f'ST_AsGeoJSON({geometry_field})::json', [])
).values(*all_fields)
```

I am not concerned by SQL injection here because these fields are in no way influenced by user input, we just have a `geom`, a `simplified_geom` or `location`.

The problem though is when the queryset is performing a join, the name "geom" can become ambiguous. `Area.objects.filter(foo=1)` is fine but `Area.objects.filter(zone__foo=1)` will fail if the zone has a geom field too.

Using parameters in RawSQL doesn't work because they're intended for values, not column names, so they're quoted.

So my question is how can I convert `geom` to the correct sql column expression like `a0.geom` ?

Full code:
    sql_injection_geom_regex = re.compile(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9_]')

```
def geojson_queryset(queryset, geometry_field, pk_field='id', fields=[]):
    """
    This method is fast way to serialize to GeoJSON a queryset. The regular serializer is extremely slow and will need
    to be parsed from text to return in a Response object. This method is roughly 20x faster.
    :param queryset: queryset to return data from
    :param geometry_field: the field to be serialized to geojson
    :param pk_field: GeoJSON requires a primary key value, defaults to 'id'
    :param fields: List of fields to include in the result
    :return: a GeoJSON FeatureCollection with the requested data.
    """
    all_fields = [pk_field, *fields, 'geojson_queryset_result']
    # Try to avoid SQL injection in the geom_field name
    if sql_injection_geom_regex.match(geometry_field):
        raise ValueError("invalid geom field name")

    features_queryset = queryset.annotate(
        geojson_queryset_result=RawSQL(f'ST_AsGeoJSON({geometry_field})::json', [])
    ).values(*all_fields)

    # features_queryset = queryset.extra(
    #     select={'geojson_queryset_result': f'ST_AsGeoJSON({geometry_field})::json'})\
    #     .values(*all_fields)

    features = []
    for row in features_queryset:
        features.append({
            'type': 'Feature',
            'id': row['id'],
            'geometry': row['geojson_queryset_result'],
            'properties': {field: row[field] for field in fields}
        })

    return {
        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'crs': {
            'type': 'name',
            'properties': {
                'name': 'EPSG:4326'
            }
        },
        'features': features
    }
```